# Formatting the output of SubstitutionSystem to create a Cantor set

Tags: plotting, graphics, formatting

I want to create a Cantor set using SubstitutionSystem, and plot it appropriately.

This is the best I've been able to do so far:

```
Column[ArrayPlot[{#}, Frame -> None, Mesh -> True] & /@ 
  SubstitutionSystem[{1 -> {1, 0, 1}, 0 -> {0, 0, 0}}, {1}, 3], 
 Spacings -> 0]
```

[image]

How can I eliminate the vertical spacing and make all ArrayPlots of the same vertical size? Toying with ImageSize hasn't given me the desired result.

The ideal output would be like the one shown below.

[image]

Edit: here's a better attempt, I'm still trying to eliminate the vertical spaces

[image]

And here's a way to generate the same output, that works on versions prior to Mathematica 10.2

```
Column[ArrayPlot[{#}, Frame -> None, AspectRatio -> 1/6, 
    Mesh -> True, ImageSize -> {550, Automatic}] &  /@ 
  NestList[Flatten[# /. {1 -> {1, 0, 1}, 0 -> {0, 0, 0}}] &, {1}, 3]]
```

Comment: Try adding the options `MeshStyle -> Black`, `ImagePadding -> None`, `PlotRangePadding -> None` to `ArrayPlot`.

Comment: Great! That's it! Thank you